# Options for accessing DDR4 DRAM memory temperature sensors?

Tags: memory, temperature

Are there linux console tools for accessing DDR4 DRAM temperature sensors on module?

Comment: Try the lm-sensors package

Comment: lm-sensors does not detect a temperature sensor, because decode-dimms shows that there is none. Thx [ https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/utils/i2c-tools/i2c-tools/+/refs/heads/master/eeprom/decode-dimms ]. Maybe others can use this information for detecting their temperature sensors on DDR4 DIMM modules.

Answer (score 0):

DDR4 DRAMs have a new driver for accessing SPD EEPROM. Thermal sensors are (unlike with previous generations of SDRAMs) integrated within the SPD. If you have a proper driver (EEPROM_EE1004), `decode-dimms` can read SPD information from a file provided by the driver to a sysfs "file". If there is a compliant thermal sensor present in the SPD it says:

```
Thermal Sensor                                   TSE2004 compliant
```

Unfortunately I didn't find a (simple) way to read the temperature, neither I found any attempt in the driver mentioned (it simply reads the pages out of SPD though, the info might be there but not decoded by the decode-dimms).

Answer (score 0):

One [manual approach](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/lm_sensors#Adding_DIMM_Temperature_sensors) for command line and **sensors** command support on Linux that's more versatile, because of the more independent (JEDEC standards and 42.4 compliant chips) **jc42 Kernel module** for SMBus specifications conformity within a strict delay range of low 25-35ms:

```
modprobe i2c-dev  
i2cdetect -l
```

select I2C™/SMBus™ adapter for chipset, e.g. smbus 1

```
i2cdetect -y 1
```

select base address for DRAM temperature sensor, e.g. 0x18 or 0x19 or 0x1a

```
modprobe jc42  
echo jc42 0x18 > /sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-1/new_device
```

select hwmon interface number and print temperature value(s)
(all available temperatures from sensors)

```
cat /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon*/device/hwmon/hwmon*/temp*_input
```

Then additionally

```
sensors
```

should output memory temperature values.

For plausible temperature values verification:
Temperature ranges for sensors seem to range from -40°C(-55°C) to 125°C and JEDEC specification (JEDEC [JC-42.4](https://www.jedec.org/committees/jc-42) Memory Module Temperature Sensor Component specification) supports a suitable output from -40°C to 85°C. Some DRAM memory manufacturers support up to 95°C upper sensor range limit. [Accuracy is at least ±3°C](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/product-selector-guide/75015693.pdf) (range from -40°C to 120°C, improved for narrower ranges) and response time for 50% thermal adjustment about 1.0-1.5s and up to 4-5 seconds for 100% thermal response.